# Finding periodic solutions of a second degree differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series, periodic-functions

Let $w\in \mathbb R$ and $p>0$. I want to find the p-periodic solutions of the differential equation
$$
f''(x)+w^2f(x)=0.
$$
Let the $p$-periodic solution be
$$
f(x)=c_0+\sum_{k \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}}c_k\exp\left(\dfrac{i2k\pi x}{p} \right).
$$ I differentiate twice and put everything in the equation and I find $$w^2c_0+\sum_{k \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}}\Big(w^2-\dfrac{4\pi^2k^2}{p^2}\Big )c_k\exp\left(\dfrac{i2k\pi x}{p} \right)=0$$

This means
$$
c_0=0 \;\text{ and }\;\Big(w^2-\dfrac{4\pi^2k^2}{p^2}\Big )c_k=0\quad\forall\,k \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}$$
Hence
$$
c_0=0 \;\text{ and }\;  c_k=0 \;\text{ or }\; w=\dfrac{2\pi k}{p}\;\text{ or }\;w=-\dfrac{2\pi k}{p}\quad\forall\,k \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{0\} \;$$

But I cannot understand  how to use the last two conditions $w=\dfrac{2\pi k}{p}\;\text{or}\;w=-\dfrac{2\pi k}{p}$ since $w$ and $p$ are fixed and given.

Comment: It means that $f(x) = c_k e^{\pm i w x}$ is a solution.

Comment: $w$ is given and fixed so how $f(x)=c_ke^{\pm i w x}$ is p-periodic. That's my problem.

Comment: if $w=0$, $f(x)=c_1 + c_2 x$ is the general solution. If $w \neq 0$, $f(x)=c_1 \sin(wx) + c_2 \cos(wx)$ is the general solution. So, unless $p=2\pi/w$ for $w \neq 0$, no p-periodic solution exists..